# Best way to Return IHttpActionResult from static class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to code a generic method to return an Internal Server Error with my Web API 2...

When an error occurs in every endpoint at my Web API I return an `InternalServerError(new Exception("This is a custom message"))`. I have several sites using the same backend with different URLs, every site has it's own exception message based on the Request URI (company1.com, company2.com, company3.com) so I have created a generic method:

```
private IHttpActionResult getCustomMessage() {
    if(Request.RequestUri.Host.Contains("company1")) {
        return InternalServerError(new Exception("Custom message for company1"));
    }
    if(Request.RequestUri.Host.Contains("company2")) {
        return InternalServerError(new Exception("Custom message for company2"));
    }
    if(Request.RequestUri.Host.Contains("company3")) {
        return InternalServerError(new Exception("Custom message for company3"));
    }
}
```

But it's a little hard to maintain a lot of this methods with the same code (one by Controller, and I have a lot of controllers), so i think that creating a Helper with the same method could help to reduce my code and make it cleaner and maintainable, but i'm having a problem, when I do this `return InternalServerError(new Exception("Custom message to company1, 2, 3"));`

I know that returning InternalServerError is a feature from ApiController, but it would be really helpfull to have that Helper.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any reason why you can't make the type InternalServerError instead of IHttpActionResult? I try to avoid making the type of a method an interface where possible and it seems you are always returning a InternalServerError

Comment: What is `InternalServerError` method? Why are you creating exceptions here? How do you use `getCustomMessage()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new extension method for the ApiController class:

```
public static class MyApiControllerExtensions
{
    public IHttpActionResult GetCustomMessage(this ApiController ctrl)
    {
        // this won't work because the method is protected
        // return ctrl.InternalServerError();

        // so the workaround is return whatever the InternalServerError returns
        if (Request.RequestUri.Host.Contains("company1")) 
        {
             return new System.Web.Http.Results.ExceptionResult(new Exception("Custom message for company1"), ctrl);
        }
        if (Request.RequestUri.Host.Contains("company2"))
        {
             return new System.Web.Http.Results.ExceptionResult(new Exception("Custom message for company2"), ctrl);
        }
        if (Request.RequestUri.Host.Contains("company3")) 
        {
             return new System.Web.Http.Results.ExceptionResult(new Exception("Custom message for company3"), ctrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the controller:

```
return this.GetCustomMessage();
```